# Article and Aside with padding

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do the cleanest code possible. Is it possible to give an article and an aside padding, margins, etc? I can't seem to figure it out. I end up adding a div with a class, and that accepts padding.

http://matthewtbrown.com/jeffandcricketquilt/index2.html

```
article {
    width:463px;
    float:left;
    padding: 40 20 0 40;
}
aside {
float: left;
}
h1 {
font-family: 'bitterregular';
font-size:16px;
}
p {
font-family: 'bitterregular';
font-size:14px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly possible. Please post specific code with the specific problems and we may be able to help.

Comment: Here is my link: http://matthewtbrown.com/jeffandcricketquilt/index2.html

Answer (score 1):

All possible with a little CSS.

**HTML**

```
<article>Article Tag</article>
<aside>Aside Tag</aside>
```

**CSS**

```
article, aside
{
    padding:5px;
    margin:10px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vwsf4/)